# Create other pages linked to main page using codeigniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I create a simple home page making at first the controller that point to it.Now inside the home page I have some links that point to another page.since I'm a newbie I' asking to what those link have to point?maybe to others controllers that points to another pages?  If so, which could be the best way to implement those controller in the index page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't understand well your question, but links to other pages are controllers/methods that build those pages.

You can also use the built-in methods to build a correct url for CI. Load the `URL helper`  (autoload it or use `$this->load->helper('url');`) and you can use:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/method');?>">Link to page</a>
```

That (the `site_url()` function) would build a correct (for CodeIgniter) link to `www.yoursite.com/index.php/controller/method`.

In your controller then you'll need to create the function (method) you asked for, and load the appropriate views.

Ex: `<a href="<?php echo site_url('blog/write');?>">Write an entry</a>`

will map to `controllers/blog.php`:

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller{

  function write()
  {
   $this->load->view('write_form');
  }
}
```

But CI's possibily the best documented framework out there, so refer to the [manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide) and this will be soon very clear.

Comment: Thank you!!It was as I imagine but you help me to make everything clearer

Comment: Glad it helped! Just ask in case of other doubts (but refer to the docs first, they're great) :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this page has all the answers for you: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
         error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
         $this->load->helper('form');

    }

    public function _remap()
    {
        $segment_1 = $this->uri->segment(1);
        switch ($segment_1) {
            case null:
            case false:
            case '':
                $this->check();
                break;
            case 'mani':
                $this->mani();
                break;
            default:
                $this->check();
                break;
        }
    }

    public function check()
    {
        echo "hasgdhsad";
    }

    public function mani(){
        echo "index";
    }
}
```